# One Group in Regex: Does it make sense?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

It works, but is there way how to remove the group "word" and still get same Matches?

```
string targetString = "5782\tabdikace\t101\r\n5705\tAbdul\t178\r\n5293\tabeceda\t590\r\n5769\tabecední\t114\r\n5651\tÁbel\t232\r\n5750\tÁber\t133\r\n5757\tAbcházie\t126\r\n5624\tAbigail\t259"

var matches = Regex.Matches(targetString, "[0-9]+\t(?<word>[^\t]+)\t[0-9]+");
foreach (Match w in matches)
{
    wordsList.Add(w.Groups["word"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [positive lookbehind and lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). These check for the *existence* of text matching a pattern before or after a point, without *including and consuming* that text in the match.

The equivalent to your expression would be

```
(?<=[0-9]+\t)[^\t]+(?=\t[0-9]+)
```

Note that this does not necessarily give the same results as your original expression. Look at the following:

```
Input string                       0\t one \t1\t two \t2\t three \t3
Groups in original version         11111111111         2222222222222
Groups in new version              ...11111...         ...3333333...
. = checked but not consumed                 ...22222...
```

Observe how, since the loohahead and lookbehind groups do not consume/match the `1` and `2`, only check they are there, they allow the value `" two "` to be matched, where your original expression did not. Whether you want this or not is up to you.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand better. Also, I have tested it and it is roughly three times slower, than my original Expression.

Comment: That is a downside, yes. Your original expression is efficient in that the engine never has to backtrack, i.e. find the start of a match, match a few characters, find something that doesn't match, then go all the way back and try again from the next character. My one will, I believe, spend some time trying to match the numbers (as they're not a tab, and they're preceeded by a tab... but then a letter, not a number, before that). Honestly, if your input is all of the format you've given (number tab word tab number newline) I'd stick with what you've got :)